# How can I separate the groups in this pandas plot?

Tags: pandas

I'm computing mean and stdev over a few indices in a multi-indexed DataFrame:

```
gp = df['measure'].groupby(level=('week', 'day', 'Inj'))
means = gp.mean()
errors = gp.std()

print means
week  day  Inj  
35    0    PBS      32.583333
           mPFFs    50.000000
      1    PBS       7.833333
           mPFFs    11.000000
      2    PBS       8.083333
           mPFFs    10.777778
      3    PBS       5.166667
           mPFFs    20.555556
37    0    PBS      16.666667
           mPFFs    -3.333333
      1    PBS       4.833333
           mPFFs    26.444444
...
```

I'd like to plot these means/error bars per `('week', 'day', 'Inj')`, with the original data scatter-plotted over top. So far, I've got this:

```
# this is just for error bars, so set box alpha=0
ax = means.plot.bar(yerr=errors, alpha=0)

X = ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()
for x, ((w, d, inj), newdf) in zip(X, gp): 
    y = newdf
    _x = np.random.normal(x, 0.05, size=len(y))
    plt.scatter(_x, y)
    plt.ylabel('time latency (s)')
```

[image]

My problem with this is that it's hard to see the different groups because the bars from `means.plot.bar` are equally spaced.

Is there a way to improve the spacing such that there's a small gap between days, and a bigger gap between weeks?

I'd be open for other suggestions for how to use the plotting tools for visualizing this data.

Comment: I almost get there with `df.unstack('Inj')` and leaving `'Inj'` off of the `groupby`; the problem with this though is that I don't seem to have any way to get the x-center of each bar, such that I can scatter-plot my jittered data.

Comment: It's far from perfect but you could add in an 4th day for each week with no data in it.

Comment: @josh There still should be be a something that separates the _days_ from each other though.